# How to send a dm with invite link to any user outside of the server with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a discord bot using discord.py that will invite users outside of the server to the server using their ID? Is there any way I can do it? So far I've only got this.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description='Bot')

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def invite(ctx, userToInvite):
        inviteLinq = await BSL.create_invite(destination = ctx.message.server, xkcd = True, max_uses = 1)
        target_user = user_id
        await BSL.send_message(target_user, inviteLinq)

bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Clearly there is lot that's wrong here since the bot doesn't even work. I don't seem to be able to generate an invite link and send it to anybody.

Comment: First things first, there's no reason to create both a Client *and* a Bot. Bot is a subclass of Client; it can do everything Client can do, plus commands. You don't use the Client you make, and you don't give your Bot your Intents.

Comment: Discord disallows a bot from direct messaging anyone outside of a server it's in. It's impossible to do so because of that unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

discord disallows a bot from sending direct messaging outside of a server.

This is a snippet for sending a dm to a user with an invite link to the server

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description='Bot')

@bot.command(name='dm',pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx, *argument):
    #creating invite link
    invitelink = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_uses=1,unique=True)
    #dming it to the person
    await ctx.author.send(invitelink)
```